# @transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED) Does this automatically commits

Tags: hibernate, spring-4

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public Users updateUser(Users user);
```

The implementation is:

```
     @Override
        public Users updateUser(Users user) {
            Session session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
            Users updateUser = (Users) session.merge(user);
            session.saveOrUpdate(updateUser);
            return updateUser;
        }
```

If I use `session.beginTransaction().commit();` then only my data is getting updated. 
But I am using @Transactional, ehich I know maintains session and transactions. Can any one tell why I need to manually put commit?

Update:

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!-- was: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>
    <!--scan the given package for controllers--> 
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.edumongoose.controllers"/> 
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.edumongoose.compilers"/> 
    <!--support for @Controller and @RequestMapping-->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <!--support for general annotations such as @Required, @Autowired, @PostConstruct, and so on.-->
    <context:annotation-config/>

     <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
<!--    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager" 
          p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory">
    </bean>

     <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />-->

</beans>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

     <!--scan the given package for repository--> 
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.edumongoose.dao"/> 
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.edumongoose.daoimpl"/> 

    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager" 
          p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory">
    </bean>

     <!--tx annotation driven scans registered spring beans for @Transactional-->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <!--support for @Controller and @RequestMapping-->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <!--support for general annotations such as @Required, @Autowired, @PostConstruct, and so on.-->
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" >
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/contest" /> 
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value=""/> 
        <property name="connection.characterEncoding" value = "utf-8"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.edumongoose.entity"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="c3p0.minPoolSize">15</prop>
                <prop key="c3p0.maxPoolSize">1000</prop>
                <prop key="c3p0.timeout">5000</prop>
                <prop key="c3p0.max_statement">500</prop>
                <prop key="c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>


</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            15
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/pagenotfound.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/500exception.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**Tiles.xml**

```
<definition name="admintemplate" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/layout/admin/admintemplate.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="admintop" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/layout/admin/admintop.jsp" />  
    <put-attribute name="adminleft" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/layout/admin/adminleft.jsp" />       
    <put-attribute name="adminbody" value="" />
    <put-attribute name="adminbottom" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/layout/admin/adminbottom.jsp" />
</definition>

<definition name="landingtemplate" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/layout/landing/landingtemplate.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Contest | Home"/>
    <put-attribute name="landingtop" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/layout/landing/landingtop.jsp" />  
    <put-attribute name="landingbody" value="" />
    <put-attribute name="landingbottom" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/layout/landing/landingbottom.jsp" />
</definition>

<definition name="errorlayout" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/layout/errorlayout.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Page Not Found" type="string" />
    <put-attribute name="errorbody" value="" />
</definition>

<definition name="home" extends="landingtemplate">

    <put-attribute name="landingbody" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/homepage.jsp" />
</definition>  

<definition name="signin" extends="landingtemplate">
    <put-attribute name="landingbody" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/signin.jsp" />
</definition>  

<definition name="signup" extends="landingtemplate">
    <put-attribute name="landingbody" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/signup.jsp" />
</definition>  

<definition name="dashboard" extends="usertemplate">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/dashboard.jsp" />
</definition>  

<definition name="solveproblem" extends="usertemplate">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/solveproblem.jsp" />
</definition>  

<definition name="listing" extends="usertemplate">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/listing.jsp" />
</definition>  

<definition name="admindashboard" extends="admintemplate">
    <put-attribute name="adminbody" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/admindashboard.jsp" />
</definition>  

<definition name="uploadproblem" extends="admintemplate">
    <put-attribute name="adminbody" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/uploadproblem.jsp" />
</definition>  

<definition name="problemlisting" extends="admintemplate">
    <put-attribute name="adminbody" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/adminproblemlisting.jsp" />
</definition>
```

Comment: you need to debug. probably your annotations are not recognised. therefore the need for adding manual commit line. You can add debug point to 1st line of your updateUser() and check the stack trace for a transaction interceptor in the trace. If not present then annotations are not working else you will have to provide configuration details

Comment: Please see my application context config. @premkumar

Comment: I got the answer. 
The component scan was twice in dispatcher as well as in application context. 
Dispatcher Servlet should contain the controller beans.

Comment: **Dispatcher Servlet** should contain the controller beans.
**Application Context** should contain the DAO and DAO implementation beans along with tx:annotation-driven.
Wrong configuration caused @transactional non functional.
I have updated the right dispatcher-servlet and applicationContext configuration.